# odd Ionic behavior in iOS simulator

Tags: ionic-framework, ios-simulator

AN Ionic application am a working on is having some odd behavior when run in the iOS simulator (Xcode 7.2.1). My login screen when normally run looks like:

[image: Normal Login]

When editing the username field however, I see some sort of toolbar popup at the bottom:

[image: Editing username]

Worse then that however is when I go over to the password field:

[image: The entire content is gone]

I thought at first that this may deal with the native WebView, but it only happens in the simulator. Not when run on the actual device or through `ionic serve`. Any ideas what is going on here? Why this odd behavior?

**EDIT**

Also, the app launches with the default **Cordova** splash screen even though I have set a splash with Ionic. Even so, it should be showing the Ionic splash as opposed to the Cordova one.

**EDIT #2**
Many times, the Cordova status bar fails to work and my status bar is black as opposed to white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this looks weird for you in iOS Simulator, and for me in Chrome's device emulator devtool, it's '*desired behaviour*' in Ionic.

[image]

Ionic is designed with mobile focus in mind, so when emulating a mobile device, they hide elements to simulate the native keyboard.

Ionic wrote [a blog post](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-keyboard/) about this, in fact:

> Getting the keyboard to play nicely with the web layer was challenging for several reasons. Probably the biggest issue is the variation in behavior across devices and platforms when the keyboard is shown.
>
> In iOS, not only does the web view resize differently when the keyboard shows in versions 6.1, 7.0, and 7.1, but it is affected differently, and sometimes completely oppositely, by including or excluding the viewport meta tag. Throw support for tablets and landscape orientation into the mix and trying to make every scenario on every device work nicely can have you quickly creating three new issues for every one you fix.

The blog post goes on to say they wrote a Keyboard plugin for Cordova, which is supposed to perform keyboard related hiding and element changing as faster and more accurately. You can find that [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard).